# random generator for multiple character vectors

Tags: r

I'm new to R and want to write a code that generates random workouts. I have 4 character vectors that look like this

```
Compound_movements <- c('Hip thrust', 'Squat', 'Deadlift')
Abduction <- c('cable aduction', 'lying plated aduction')
Upper <- c('good mornings', 'kneeling squat')
Maxiums <- c('smith machine kick backs', 'cable kickbacks', 'single leg hipthrusts' )
G_H_tie_in <- c('stomp downs' )
```

I want to code that will pick out and then print 1 or 2 exercises from each vector. What are the best functions for this?

Comment: For each one, `sample(x, size=1)` will give you one of each. If all of those are in one `list`, then `lapply(lst_of_workouts, sample, size = 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample` is what I think you need.

```r
set.seed(42) # R-4.0.2
sample(Compound_movements, size = 1)
# [1] "Hip thrust"
sample(Compound_movements, size = 1)
# [1] "Hip thrust"
sample(Compound_movements, size = 1)
# [1] "Hip thrust"
sample(Compound_movements, size = 1)
# [1] "Hip thrust"
sample(Compound_movements, size = 1)
# [1] "Squat"
```

(Yes, apparently you'll do hip thrusts four times in a row ... random is random.)

If those are stored in a list of exercises, you can pick one from each with:

```r
lst_of_exercises <- list(
  Compound_movements = c('Hip thrust', 'Squat', 'Deadlift'),
  Abduction = c('cable aduction', 'lying plated aduction'),
  Upper = c('good mornings', 'kneeling squat'),
  Maxiums = c('smith machine kick backs', 'cable kickbacks', 'single leg hipthrusts' ),
  G_H_tie_in = c('stomp downs' )
)

sapply(lst_of_exercises, sample, size = 1)
#      Compound_movements               Abduction                   Upper                 Maxiums              G_H_tie_in 
#                 "Squat" "lying plated aduction"         "good mornings" "single leg hipthrusts"           "stomp downs"
```

And if you need to do other than the same number for all (e.g., 2 of one group, 1 of the others), then perhaps

```r
Map(sample, lst_of_exercises, size = c(1,1,1,2,1))
# $Compound_movements
# [1] "Deadlift"
# $Abduction
# [1] "lying plated aduction"
# $Upper
# [1] "good mornings"
# $Maxiums
# [1] "smith machine kick backs" "cable kickbacks"         
# $G_H_tie_in
# [1] "stomp downs"
```